# I18N, translating in template variables

Tags: 7, theming, i18n-l10n

I've got a theme setup, and this theme has a header region (region--header.tpl.php). There are some small ui elements in this template that require translation, but are not tied to blocks, views or nodes. My understanding is that when using something like `<?php print t('Select a topic'); ?>` it should become available to the translation backend. But it does not for me? I have the I18N module and Multilingual Variables module installed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah I found that one needs to view the site in another language than English in order to have the strings to be registered.